# I am in the UK, my family is in India, where do we apply for a Schengen visa if we want to visit together?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

I am a student in UK but my wife and son are in India. They are visiting me shortly in the UK on a visit visa and I plan to take them to a few places in Europe (France, Italy and Switzerland) when they are here. I intend to apply at the Italian consulate as I will be spending the most time there. I can apply for Schengen visa in UK. As I will be bearing all their expenses for their Europe trip and providing UK bank statements, will they be able to apply for Schengen visa in UK or do they still have to apply back in India before coming to the UK.

Comment: For sure they can apply in India, it is arguably preferred because the evidence can be obtained there. For the UK, there is no single policy governing for visiting family members of a temporary migrant (T4). So it works on a consulate-by-consulate basis and you did not identify the consulate. Accordingly I will mark your question as 'unclear', sorry...

Comment: @GayotFow it's actually *required* that they apply in India, since Schengen consulates are required by the visa code to consider applications only from those who reside in the consulate's service area. There are some exceptions, but they mostly involve unavoidable unforseen circumstances.